# How can i Filter records on column type return by jdbcCursorItemReader and process same kind of records at the same time in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

How can I fetch record for a unique I'd at a time using jdbccursoritem reader and process them and then fetch records for another id and then process.

Comment: I am trying to read and process all the records for one batch id at a time, say i have 3 batch ids, 1, 2, & 3. and for every batch ids i have some records for delete and update. I want to process all delete record first and then update.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement goes slightly against the main idea of processing records. If your bussiness logic requires that the records of the same batch id are processed together, you can try making an enclosing class (BatchIdRecords?) that represents a batch id and includes all the records in that batch id. This way you'll have a ItemReader, and a similar processor, which can deal with them, as you want, Delete first, and then Update.

The query of the reader will have to sort by batch id, and maybe do some manual buffering (ugh) unless you can aggregate them beforehand.

This has nothing to do with spring batch configuration, though.